# Windows Phone 8.1 play audio data stream through speaker?

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, stream, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I receive over network PCM audio data stream and this part works fine so I am ending up with

```
DataReader incomming = args.GetDataReader();
byte[] RcvBuffer = new byte[incomming.UnconsumedBufferLength];
incomming.ReadBytes(RcvBuffer);
```

I have all audio data in buffer.

How I can play this through telephone Speaker ? Can you point me in some direction ?

Thanks

Comment: look up the `MediaElement` for WP8/8.1

Comment: Thanks Neil for comment, I did look at MediaElement and it has most of stuff that I need, I have one problem in all of this: How to connect my buffer with media element.

Comment: That's for you to figure out - lots of info out there on how `MediaElement` works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're many ways to do that.

You can prepend the WAVE header to your data, and use MediaElement for playback, see [the documentation for SetSource method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190669(v=vs.95).aspx).

If however by “telephone speaker” you mean the earphone, then it is only possible if you are [creating a VoIP app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206983(v=vs.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It took a while but I sorted it, maybe someone else will need help in the future.

- **First Problem** - since I just started app development for Windows Phone I have chosen **Blank App (Windows Phone)** instead **Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight)** and I did not have access to many features that are available in Silverlight projects, so my suggestions for beginners: understand what each project is for.

Like [Soonts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126995/soonts) said there are many ways to do this, this is one that I used.

**I simplified this code and retyped this so there can be some typos.**

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using System.IO;
```

1) Create Stream to load your incoming data:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
```

2) Load data from buffer to stream:

```
stream.Write(RcvBuffer, 0, RcvBuffer.Length);
```

3) I am using SoundEfect to play this through Loud-Speaker. Sample rate that I use is 8 kHz

```
SoundEffect sound;
sound = new SoundEffect(stream.toArray(), 8000, AudioChannels.Mono)
sound.Play();
```